# What is meant by ‘NEE’ in computer graphics?

Tags: pathtracing, lighting

I am reading this paper [[Practical Path Guiding for Efficient Light-Transport Simulation, Müller et al, 2017]](https://studios.disneyresearch.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/Practical-Path-Guiding-for-Efficient-Light-Transport-Simulation.pdf) and it contains the following sentence:

> In practice, however, we recommend combining path-guiding with NEE via multiple importance sampling due to the ease of im- plementation and low performance overhead.

What does NEE stand for? I have found some other authors using this abbreviation, but no explanation.

Comment: Next event estimation. It is when you sample a point on a light surface and then connect to it from the current vertex. It's also known as a shadow ray. It's basically integration over the surface area of light sources.

Comment: It's also known as light sampling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"NEE" stands for Next Event Estimation algorithm.
For learning more about this algorithm, you can watch [this presentation from TU Wien](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FU1dbi827LY) or have a look on [their presentation slides](https://www.cg.tuwien.ac.at/sites/default/files/course/4411/attachments/08_next%20event%20estimation.pdf).

Also, you can find a useful piece of code for NEE in [this presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i6KDgYk5Nzg).